# React native notification push using strapi

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, strapi

I’m developing an application using react native, and I’m going to deal with the push notifications. So I was looking for some information and tutorials but there is none ressources about sending notifications push using strapi, all the ressources are with th following stack : “Expo + firebase + React Native”.

So I have some questions :

Is it possible to send push notifications using strapi ?

Is it possible to send push notifications using firebase even if I'm using strapi ?

Do I have to do somthing inside strapi if (for example) I want to send an notification every time I add an article in my strapi backend ?

thank you for helping

Comment: Why not use fcm or One Signal?
Also here's the article that might come in handy https://medium.com/strapi/strapi-socket-io-a9c856e915a6

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer !! I'm going to check that quickly! So according of what you said it's possible to send notification push with fcm ? Firstly I will try to add push notification not dynamically, and then I will see if I can automate some task ;)